# SQL one to many with inner join

Tags: sql, join

Say I have two tables, table 1 and table 2. Table 1 has a one to many relationship with table 2.

If table 1 is my base table (`SELECT something FROM table1`) with an inner join to table 2, then what values from table two would be returned when selecting any fields from table 2?

- The first value returned? As with excel's vlookup function?
- The last value on the join?

E.G.

```
Table1
     Account ID |      email      
         1      |   abc@def.com
         2      |   cats@dogs.com
         3      |   ex@example.com

Table 2
Subscription ID | Account ID  |       Email       |      Created
    100         |     1       |    abc@def.com    |    2014-01-01
    102         |     2       |    cats@dogs.com  |    2014-02-02
    103         |     1       |    abc@def.com    |    2014-03-03
```

So if I ran a query to select the created date of an account based on subscriptions I could just run `SELECT min(Created)` to get the first one.

But what's the default behavior? If my left table is table 1 joined onto table 2 on account ID and I select created field, which will be returned? 2014-01-01 or 2014-03-03?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would return both records. When you `JOIN` tables, you get all the records that meet the criteria of the `JOIN` and the `WHERE` clauses and any `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` clauses. If you want only one returned, you have to write the code to specify which one you want.

Comment: Both records. Many thanks I did not even consider that.